# ResolveUrl without an ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resolveurl

I am looking for a way to resolve a relative url the way you would with a page or control instance ([MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.71).aspx)) such as:

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/common/Error.aspx");
```

...but when I only have an HttpContext available to me, such as when I am in a HttpHandler.

Will I need to use a custom function, such as the one seen [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/154812.aspx)?

Or is there a way to get at the underlying function used by the Page.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try to get the page from the handler and use [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx), or create a Control object...

```
(HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page).ResolveUrl("~/virtualpath");
```

Or use [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150163.aspx) or [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160.aspx)

For example:

```
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Styles/Contoso.xslt");
```

returns

```
/WebSite/Styles/Contoso.xslt
```

Comment: in an `IHTTPHandler` and `IHttpModule` `HttpContext.Current.Handler` is null!

Answer (score 17):

This question on SO ([ASP.Net: Using System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveUrl() in a shared/static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796/asp-net-using-system-web-ui-control-resolveurl-in-a-shared-static-function)) looks kind of helpful...Basically, you can use the [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) class which is under the System.Web namespace. There is an additional answer to that question which says to be careful of QueryString parameters, but a solution to that is also provided.

At the same time, Rick Strahl's code is pretty neat!

Comment: which ***good patterns and practices*** ? `System.Web.VirtualPathUtility`, `HttpContext.Current.Handler` or `Rick Strahl's code` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this - 
Controls is a folder name in your application and myController is the controller name. to create and instance and load the controller you can do it by:

```
Controls_myController ctrl = Page.LoadControl(Page.ResolveUrl("controls/myController.ascx"));
```

Hope this helps.