# I would like to display images from an absolute path

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to store my images in a directory, say

```
C:/Photos
```

But to display these images in my application using the img element, I have to use a pathname that is relative to my project directory.
For example

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/photos/image.jpg")">
```

Instead of doing that, is there a way I can use an absolute pathname instead, or is it impossible?

Comment: `file:///c:/photos/image.jpg` if no server

Comment: Try using: @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/photos/image.jpg")
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936372/2048391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute path names if you really want, of course. They would start with a single backslash on windows ("\").

In a typical production environment (webserver) you can link to your images with the full http address also in an absolute way:

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" />
```

But beware of the problems this may bring when you switch to a different machine etc.

Comment: So for the C:/Photos directory it will be "\Photos"?

Comment: I think this should work, yes. You can also try "file:///C:/Photos/image.jpg". But who should be able to view this page, only people using your local computer?

Comment: I was thinking it would be stored on the C drive of the server. But of course the point you are making is that it will not be. What I want to avoid is having a directory relative to the project folder.

Comment: It is very likely that your server will be a Unix environment, and as such there will not even be a "C drive" but a Unix path. You will however be able to address your image with an absolute path still, in the fashion of the example in the original answer. Still I am doubting absolute paths are really required - what is the reason you want them? -- If the answer has helped you, you can upvote it and mark it as "correct answer".

Comment: I am using windows. When I log onto the server I see a directory structure similar to my local PC with a C drive and others. In your original answer, is the images folder relative for the project folder? If not where can it be found?

Comment: Post the link to your website please. In my original answer I showed as an example an absolute http path. Where to find it on the drive depends on where the *web server's* root directory is. Most likely it will be the one into which you put your index.html file or such.