# How to give a correct path to file in Asp.net Web.form?

Tags: asp.net

I am having troubles with including files into my website after publishing it on server. The `website` is called "shop" and located in `wwwroot` folder. The `website` doesn't read scripts, which are located like this: `shop/app_themes/grey/js/site.js.` How to give the correct path to script files? I used `~, ../, ../../` and doesn't help..

Answer (score 0):

User `Server.MapPath` Methos the details are below

```
Server.MapPath(path)
```

You can use [`Resolve Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Example

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205425/ASP-NET-ResolveUrl-Without-Page
2. [ResolveUrl without an ASP.NET Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893380/resolveurl-without-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: Doesn't help. That will get you the local path, not the relative server url.

Comment: I have an error for js file "uncaught reference error $ is not defined (anonymous function)". can it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if u want host url then try this

```
public string GetHostUrl()
            {
                var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                var appUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

                if (appUrl == null || appUrl == "" || appUrl != "/")
                {
                    appUrl += "/";
                }

                var baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, appUrl);

                return baseUrl;
            }
```

or else you want physical path then try this

```
public string GetPhysicalPath()
    {
        string PhysicalPath = "";

        if (Application["instancePath"] != null && Convert.ToString(Application["instancePath"]) != "")
        {
            PhysicalPath = Convert.ToString(Application["instancePath"]);
        }
        else
        {
            PhysicalPath = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath);
        }

        return PhysicalPath;
    }
}
```